# Python syntaxError: invalid syntax in for loop with 'equal' sign while trying to append a simple math equation to a .txt file

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am trying to write a math equation to a .txt file and receive a 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'.

The issue specifically is:

```
File "<string>", line 1
   1+1 = 2
       ^
```

This is my code and just cannot seem to crack or understand where my logic is failing. Please help me.

```
# function to check whether the input is operator or not
def isOperator(o):
    if len(o) not in [1, 2]:
        return False
    return True if o in ['+', '-', '*', '/', '//', '**'] else False
# function to check whether the input is number or not
def isNumber(n):
    for i in n:
        if not i.isdigit():
            return False
    return True
def isFileValid(name):
    try:
        r = open(name, 'r')
        r.close()
        return True
    except :
        print('File does not exist....')
        return False
# main function
def main():
    while True:
        print('1. Read input from User\n2. Read input from a File')
        choice = input('Enter choice : ')
        if isNumber(choice) and choice in ['1', '2']:
            choice = int(choice)
            break
        print('Enter valid choice')
        
    eqs = []
    if choice == 1:
        # read input until a valid one is given
        while True:
            n1 = input('Enter number 1 : ')
            if isNumber(n1):
                break
        # read input until a valid one is given
        while True:
            n2 = input('Enter number 2 : ')
            if isNumber(n2):
                break
        # read input until a valid one is given
        while True:
            op = input('Enter operator : ')
            if isOperator(op):
                break
        eqs = [n1+op+n2]
    elif choice == 2:
        while True:
            file_name = input('Enter file name : ')
            if isFileValid(file_name):
                break
        r = open(file_name, 'r')
        if r is None:
            print('SS')
        for i in r:
            if '\n' in i:
                i = i[:-1]
            eqs.append(i)
        r.close()
        
    # create a file if it doesn't exists
    f = open('e.txt', 'a')
    for e in eqs:
        ans = e + '=' + str(eval(e))
        # write the equation and the solution to the file
        f.write(ans+'\n')
        print(ans)
    # close the file
    f.close()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Apologies for the long code I just thought that context would be better for the reader.

Comment: What is the data in text file??

Comment: @codester_09 1+1=2. If the user decides to input more equations then the equations must be writeable to the e.txt file and if a user would like to read then they must be able to read all the equations from the e.txt file.

Comment: What are you expecting your code to *do* with that line?  If you choose the option to enter the equation from the keyboard, you'd only be typing in the `1+1` part, the `2` would be the *output*.

Comment: @jasonharper. Yes. In essence, Choice1: a users inputs a 1st number then a 2nd number then an operator (+,-,*,/) and then the equation calculates and writes its to the .txt file. Then if another user would like to see what data is in the folder then they would be able to read what equations are in the folder by selection of Choice2

Comment: But that's not at all what Choice2 is doing - it's evaluating the equations from the file, just like Choice1 evaluates equations from the keyboard.  You'd have to strip off the `=` and everything after it for that to make any sense.

Comment: @jasonharper. Apologies Choice2 would be done by user inputting the _.txt file_ name and then being able to print the equations in the specific file. I do also see what you mean by evaluating the equation in Choice2.